# What's the convergence condition for the generating function formula of Legendre polynomials?

Tags: special-functions, limits-and-convergence, generating-functions, legendre-polynomials

What is the convergence condition of the next infinite series about the Legendre polynomials $P_n(x)$?
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(x)t^n
$$
I know it is convergent at least when $|t|<1$ and $|x|\le 1$. This is sufficient when I'm using it for the multipole expansion in physics. But are there any other regions on the $t-x$ plane where it converges?

Comment: You can try $x>1$, $|t| < x-\sqrt{x^2-1}$.  For fixed $x>1$, this is the distance from $0$ to the nearest singularity as a function of $t$.

Comment: Also works for $x < -1$.  And (as stated) for $-1 \le x \le1$ , the two complex singularities are distance $1$ from $0$.

Comment: For any fixed complex $x$, the radius of convergence with respect to $t$ is the distance from 0 to the closest singularity (in other words, the absolute value of the least root of the quadratic trinomial $1 - 2tx+t^2$).